# how to change button action after text change of button in android

Tags: android, onclick, android-button, buttonclick

I am developing an application in which there is a login page. If user successfully login, then the Login button will change to logout. For this I am using `login.setText("Logout");` . But I want to change the action too for this button. That means if user clicks on logout which was login before text change of login, then the page will redirect to login page. I am not getting any idea how to change the action after text change of button. Please give me some clues....

Comment: Have you tried testing against the text? if (login.getText() == "my text") {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public class Test extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private boolean isLogin = true;
    private static final String TEXT_LOGIN = "Login", TEXT_LOGOUT = "Logout";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.your_lauyout);

        final Button btnLoginLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login_logout);
        // Initialize the button with Login text
        btnLoginLogout.setText(TEXT_LOGIN);
        // Set the click listener for the button
        btnLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_login_logout:
                if (isLogin) {
                    // Login action
                    ((Button)v).setText(TEXT_LOGOUT);
                    isLogin = false;
                } else {
                    // Logout action
                    ((Button)v).setText(TEXT_LOGIN);
                    isLogin = true;
                    // Redirect here or do an custom action
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

        btnLoginLogout.setText("Login");
        btnLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(((Button)v).getText().equals("Login")){
                    ((Button)v).setText("Logout");
                    // do your login code here
                }else{
                    ((Button)v).setText("Login");
                    // do your login code here
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your login button onClick Listener
Try this way

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    if(login.getText().toString().equals("Login")){
    doLogin(); //login functionality here
    }else{
    doLogout();//logout functionality here
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be

```
         logOutButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()){

               @Override
               public void onClick(View view){

                   String buttonText =  logOutButton.getText().toString();

                   if(buttonText.equalsIgnoreCase("Login")){

                       //let the user login, and change to logout after

                   }else if(buttonText.equalsIgnoreCase("Logout")){

                       //let the user logout and change to login after

                    }
             }

         });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
     String buttonText =  logOutButton.getText().toString();
     if(buttonText.equalsIgnoreCase("Login")){   
          // logIn code here                    
          view.setText("Logout");
     }else{
          // logOut code here
          view.setText("Login");
        }
     }
```